# Filter array problem inside React with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, filtering

I've been trying to remove an item from my array for a while now but the filter removes too much.

My array:

```
[
    {
        "domain": "domain1.com",
        "slug": "monitor"
    },
    {
        "domain": "domain1.com",
        "slug": "monitor-1"
    },
    {
        "domain": "domain2.com",
        "slug": "monitor"
    }
]
```

I release the following filter

```
array.filter((item) => item.slug !== 'monitor')
```

This removed all my results exclude slug monitor-1, which is correct since I am asking the slug with monitor to remove.

Result:

```
[
    {
        "domain": "domain1.com",
        "slug": "monitor-1"
    },
]
```

But i only want to remove the slug monitor from domain1.com and not domain2.com

```
array.filter((item) => item.slug !== 'monitor' && item.domain !== 'domain1.com)
```

This will remove all the result so the array is empty

```
[]
```

How can I make it so that I get it like this, without deleting everything?
So only delete the domain: domain1.com with the slug: monitor.

```
[
    {
        "domain": "domain1.com",
        "slug": "monitor-1"
    },
    {
        "domain": "domain2.com",
        "slug": "monitor"
    }
]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `item.domain !== 'domain1.com` not be `item.domain === 'domain1.com'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct,just need to change the expression in `Array.filter()`,below is a reference for you

```js
let data = [
    {
        "domain": "domain1.com",
        "slug": "monitor"
    },
    {
        "domain": "domain1.com",
        "slug": "monitor-1"
    },
    {
        "domain": "domain2.com",
        "slug": "monitor"
    },
    {
        "domain": "domain2.com",
        "slug": "monitor-1"
    }
]

let result = data.filter(d => !(d.slug === 'monitor-1' && d.domain === 'domain1.com'))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this removed all "monitor-1". Is it possible to also remove only the "monitor-1" from "domain2.com" and leave the other 3 options?

Comment: @webthesign You can test my code,it will not remove all `montior-1`

Comment: @webthesign this will work similarly to other answer because `(NOT A) OR (NOT B)` is equivalent to `NOT(A AND B)` in boolean logic (de morgan law)

Answer (score 4):

The item will be kept if the callback returns true and you want to keep it either when the `item.slug !== 'monitor'` *OR* when `item.domain !== 'domain1.com'`

```js
const input = [
    {
        "domain": "domain1.com",
        "slug": "monitor"
    },
    {
        "domain": "domain1.com",
        "slug": "monitor-1"
    },
    {
        "domain": "domain2.com",
        "slug": "monitor"
    }
]

console.log(input.filter((item) => (item.slug !== 'monitor' || item.domain !== 'domain1.com')))
```

Comment: Thanks! Stupid, It's OR and not AND ;-). It works!!